# How to Justify this Two-Sided Test is UMP with NP Lemma?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, uniform-distribution, neyman-pearson-lemma

UMP tests generally do not exist for two sided tests, ie $H_0: \theta = \theta_0$ vs $H_a: \theta \neq \theta_0$. However, if we observe $n$ iid observations of $X\sim Unif(0,\theta)$, we can construct a UMP test for the two sided hypothesis.

The general strategy is to look at both sides of the inequality, ie $\theta < \theta_0$ and $\theta > \theta_0$. If we can show that the power function of the two sided test coincides with the powers of the individual one sided tests, the two sided test is UMP.

(From here on, let $X_{(n)} = \max (X_1,...,X_n)$ )

So consider $\psi(X)$ as the test for $\theta < \theta_0$. We can show by MLR, that if we choose $k$ such that $P(X_{(n)} < k) = \alpha$, then we have a UMP test by rejecting when $X_{(n)} < k$. This $k$ turns out to be $\alpha^{1/n}\theta_0$. This test has poweras a function of $\theta$ = $\beta(\theta) = P(X_{(n)} < \alpha^{1/n}\theta_0;\theta) = 1$ when $\theta < \alpha^{1/n}\theta_0$ and is $(\frac{\theta_0}{\theta})^{n}\alpha$ for $\theta > \alpha^{1/n}\theta_0$. Another test of equal power turns out to be to reject when $X_{(n)}<\theta_0$ with probability $\alpha$ and to fail to reject when $X_{(n)} \geq \theta_0$.

So the two tests are:

$$
\phi_1(X)=
\begin{cases}
1 & X_{(n)}\leq \alpha^{1/n}\theta_0 \\\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases} \qquad
\phi_2(X)=
\begin{cases}
\alpha & X_{(n)}\leq \theta_0 \\\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases} \qquad
$$

For the test in the other direction, $H_a: \theta > \theta_0$, we can derive the UMP test by monotone likelihood ratio, and another tests with the same power function:

$$
\psi_1(X)=
\begin{cases}
1 & X_{(n)}\geq (1-\alpha)^{1/n}\theta_0 \\\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases} \qquad
\psi_2(X)=
\begin{cases}
1 & X_{(n)} > \theta_0 \\\\
\alpha & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

So if in the two sided test, we reject when $X_{(n)} < \alpha^{1/n}\theta_0$, (adopted from the $\phi_1$ test) or when $X_{(n)} > \theta_0$ (adopted from the $\psi_2$ test), then we get a two sided test $\gamma$:

$$
\gamma = 
\begin{cases}
1 & X_{(n)} > \theta_0 \text{ or } X_{(n)} < \alpha^{1/n}\theta_0 \\\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

A quick calculation for power shows that both the powers for $\phi_{1,2}$ are $\beta_\phi(\theta) = \min \left(1, (\theta_0/\theta)^n\alpha \right)$

A quick calculation for power shows that both the powers for $\psi_{1,2}$ are $\beta_\psi(\theta) = \max\left(0, 1-(\theta_0/\theta)^n(1-\alpha)\right)$

Calculating the power for the two sided test $\gamma$, we see that $\beta_\gamma(\theta) = \max\left(\beta_\phi(\theta), \beta_\psi(\theta) \right)$.

Using some arbitrary numbers, I have plotted on Desmos, (Purple: power for testing $\theta < \theta_0$, red: power for testing $\theta > \theta_0$, Dotted: power for testing two sided test):

As it turns out, the power for the two sided test is the same as the power for when testing each side. This is my argument for why the two sided test is UMP.

I noticed that we could also construct another two sided test, with the same power, which is by combining rejection regions of $\phi_1$ and $\psi_1$.

Is this the general strategy to justifying this two sided test being UMP, and does this strategy also work to show if a particular test is not UMP? In what other cases does a two sided UMP test arise? Also, the NP Lemma tells us that for sample point $x$ and any two parameters $\theta_1,\theta_0$, if $\frac{f(x;\theta_1)}{f(x;\theta_0)} > k$ then $x$ is in the rejection region region, otherwise it is in the acceptance region. I just don't see how this particular test is justifiable with NP lemma.

This is not homework.

[image: Power Plot]

Comment: I believe you have made an error in your calculation of the power for your two-sided test: you can't use $\alpha$ as in each of the one-sided tests but rather $\frac{\alpha}{2}$ (or $\alpha_L+\alpha_R=\alpha$) (you can also check this is necessary by simulation).

As a result the calculated power is the sum (in your notation), $\beta_\phi(\theta,\frac{\alpha}{2})+\beta_\psi(\theta,\frac{\alpha}{2})$.